# When made to JAR: Unable to run app:- NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, swing, exception, jar, noclassdeffounderror

```
public class BeatBox {          

    JPanel mainPanel;
    ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxList;
    Sequencer sequencer;
    Sequence sequence;
    Track track;
    JFrame theFrame;            
    String[] instrumentNames = {"Bass Drum", "Closed Hi-hat", "Open Hi-Hat"} 
    int[] instruments = {35,42,46,38,49,39,50,60,70,72,72,64,56,58,47,67,63};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BeatBox().buildGUI();
}

public void buildGUI(){
    theFrame = new JFrame("Cyber BeatBox");
    theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // Followed by Remaining Events code;         
}           
}
```

---

```
public class BeatBoxM {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BeatBox b = new BeatBox();
    b.buildGUI();
}
}
```

Created a Jar file for a BeatBox application
It has two class files one is BeatBoxM which has the main method
Another class is BeatBox which has the gui and event part.

Since it has inner classes after compiling got inner classes .class files as well. Made the application to a jar file which contains the manifest of class name of main method.

While running the application getting `NoClassDefFounderror`.

Could some one help on sorting it?

Comment: 1) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: *"BeatBoxM which has the main method"* Both classes have a main method which does identical actions.

Comment: Could you share some code inside "Remaining events"? it runs in my ide, but JFrame doesn't appear..

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson it worked after recompiling removing the main method in BeatBox class.

Comment: Now you have two courses of action to finalize this: 1) Enter an answer below, and accept it when the site allows. 2) Delete the question using the link below left of it, under the question tags.